# How to curve fit to a log curve in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have some code in a Gnuplot file that does curve fitting, currently to a line:

```
f(x) = m * x + b
fit f(x) "data.txt" using "Days":"Data" via m, b
```

This works great, but the data looks like it will fit a log curve better. So I tried the following:

```
f(x) = b + m * log(x)
fit f(x) "data.txt" using "Days":"Data" via m, b
```

This results in the following error:

```
line 46: unknown type in real()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the internals of how `fit` works, but if `x` ever goes negative, `log(x)` becomes a complex number, which `fit` may not be prepared to deal with (assuming `gnuplot`s `log()` implementation even works for negative numbers, instead of returning a "domain error" or other similar condition)...

Comment: @twalberg Thanks. x will never go negative for me. Is there a way to constrain it?

Comment: Fitting to non polynomials is usually a bad idea if you can avoid it. If your data looks like a log, then try fitting to a linear function but using preprocessed data, e.g. `fit a*x+b "data" using (log($1)):2 via a,b` or something like that. Show your data if you want better help figuring out the actual problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue. My data set was small (8 points) on a semi-log plot. When trying to fit, I also received `

> unknown type in real()`

I changed my initial parameter estimates and everything works. Hopefully, that helps.